Could asteroid mining be made viable if there were a resource rich asteroid in orbit just beyond the moon?
Two of the biggest issues with asteroid mining is the issue of actually getting materials from the the asteroid in question back to earth, and the relative abundance of resources on earth vs in space. However, how would the economics be changed if there were an asteroid like 16 Psyche in orbit just far enough beyond the moon to have a stable orbit, how would the economics change?
The technology available is largely that of the mid 2010s but with NASA/EPA going through with the solar power satellite program, with the expected rate of 2 new solar power satellites a year built every year between 2000 and 2030. This means the space infrastructure you would expect associate with an undertaking that large underway and launch craft similar to the Rockwell Star Raker and/or Boeing Space Freighter in use and the capability to build more for other uses. This means drastically lower launch costs and an existing in-space market to start off with even if very limited relative to earth.
Crashing the market isn't a concern as how much can be extracted will be monitored by a government agency trying to keep the commodity market on earth intact. The same agency also provides grants and contracts to provide funding to help develop necessary technology.

The [tag:science-based] tag scopes the answers, not the question. What about economic impact do you think is science-based beyond the basic application of mathematics? To make my point, I give you the very profitable pet rock.

The important problem to consider: every reasonably sized bit of asteroid that is mined, becomes a weapon of mass destruction when towed to Earth's orbit. A shipping of say, 2000 tons of palladium ore is a city-leveling kinetic weapon when mishandled. Thus preventing a low end apocalypitc scenario would then become the biggest economic and technological hurdle to overcome.

"Crashing the market isn't a concern as how much can be extracted will be monitored by a government agency trying to keep the commodity market on earth intact." This may be much harder than you think for gold, which isn't really a commodity in the same sense as Iron ore or wheat. The vast majority of gold is held for investment purposes and the market is driven buy sentiment. Once it is announced that gold is being mined from asteroids it is very hard to predict how the gold market would react regardless of whatever government controls were in place ~$160 billions worth is traded every day

Depends on the specific resource. Gold, yes, sure. Anything else, no, not really.
The fundamental problem is that transportation capacity from near-Earth orbit down to the surface is severely limited. Let's say you arrange with SpaceX to launch one Super Heavy booster carrying one Starship every day, and each Starship can bring back 100 tonnes of stuff. (It cannot, but let's assume SpaceX continues to refine the design so that it can.) That's 100 tonnes of stuff per day, or 36,500 tonnes per year. Suppose that you pay 50 million US dollars for each mission.
What kind of resource is that which has such a low yearly production rate?

Iridium! Worldwide production of iridium is some 7 or 8 tonnes per year. Price is about 150,000 US dollars per kg. If you find a market for it, 100 tonnes of iridium would bring you 15 billion dollars. Almost pure profit.
Unfortunately, the worldwide consumption of iridium is also some 7 tonnes per year. 100 tonnes of iridium would cover the industry needs for about 14 years...

Gold! Worldwide production of gold is about 3,000 tonnes per year. Price is about 60,000 US dollars per kg. Each Starship bringing 100 tonnes of gold will earn 6 billion US dollars. Almost pure profit.
Unfortunately, by increasing tenfold the amount of gold availabe per year, the prices will surely crash, down to somewhere near the "natural" price of about 10,000 USD/kg. (Estimated by taking the 35 US dollars per troy ounce stipulated in the Bretton Woods agreement and applying the inflation from 1965 to present.) Still, each Starship with 100 tonnes of gold will net about 1 billion dollars. Not bad.

Silver? Worldwide production of silver is some 28,000 tonnes per year, comparable with the 36,000 tonnes which can imaginably be brought down by using one SpaceX Starship per day. But unfortunately the price of precious silver is only about 600 US dollars per kg, 600,000 per tonne. Each Starship bringing 100 tonnes of silver will earn a revenue of about 60 million dollars; minus 50 million dollars cost of the mission remains a profit of 10 million dollars. Maybe good enough, maybe not.

Anything else is not really worth bringing down from orbit...



why do you have to bring down 100 tonnes a day? Why can't less be brought down to avoid crashing the market?

@OT-64SKOT: That's a cost-benefit analysis, which I expect the business managers to do. Yes, there is a sweet spot where the profit is maximized. But on the other hand, when we speak about exploiting resources we normally speak large volumes. Stuff which is needed in homeopathic quantities is not normally considered an important resource.

Why send a rocket to get the stuff? Wouldn't it make more sense to manufacture capsules in orbit and just drop them, using far less fuel?

If the asteroid contains a lot of ice, I bet you could get the lunar colonies to pay a pretty penny for virtually-unlimited water that's still way cheaper than lifting valuable Earth water all the way out of the planet's gravity well. (Fundamentally, I agree with your points.)

"Unfortunately, the worldwide consumption of iridium is also some 7 tonnes per year. 100 tonnes of iridium would cover the industry needs for about 14 years...": that's mainly because that's all that's available though, hence the high price. Iridium and other platinum group elements have enough industrial uses that it might be worth it for a government to subsidize their retrieval specifically to lower their prices and allow wider use for strategic reasons, even if market forces wouldn't support it. Guaranteeing a supply of cheap palladium for US chemical industry could be worth something...

The markets will react to the knowledge that precious metals are being brought back from space and the consequence will be the greatest amount o financial pain for the greatest number of people (at least that's how the markets usual seem to work) and those vested in space mining will not be immune.

speaking of refining designs, I think you are talking about refined material, not raw ore. Technically you could refine in space, but that is going to be some pretty big expense to create a refinery which can refine into metal bars and also not itself melt

Ok, yes.  But with caveats.  Building on AlexP's answer, you can't rely on existing high value, high rarity prices alone.  And given the existing rarity of those elements it's unlikely that your asteroid would have tonnes of the materials.   But that's fine.
Because we're going to exploit the price difference based on location.
A litre of water in London is worth 2-3 pounds. In a desert... it's somewhat higher.  In orbit, the cost is approximately the launch price in 10s to 100s of thousands of pounds.  How much is dictated by your allowed tech level.
At which point what you do is mine it and use the material to support your other endeavours... and you start with oxygen.
But, I hear you cry, that's free!  To which I say "lol".  Most of our current large set of available rockets use liquid oxygen... tonnes and tonnes.  Imagine if you only had to make it to a low orbit, not even truly a stable one, and then feed off of a huge tanker full of the stuff. Once you've taken enough, you (and the tanker) move off to somewhere more civilised.
But each tonne has saved you 10-100k pounds.
At this point you've cracked a very, very large part of the Rocket Equation.  You have partial refueling - more than half the weight of your propellant is oxygen.  This makes everything else you want to do easier, while at the same time giving you free building materials to do something silly.  Oh, I don't know, rotating station anyone?
But you're making a "profit" with just the oxygen, which you can guarantee is present on your rock, bound to the metals.  Because it's one of the most common elements.
Heck, worst case, sell the iron in the NASA gift shop in the form of plaques.  "I visited NASA and all I got was this poxy asteroid"

If: Water Ice.
This might not seem overly impressive at first sight, but think... The cost of getting mass into orbit is impressively high at present and takes many trips to get anything substantially heavy up there. The celestial body doesn't need to be pure ice, but perhaps not far beneath the crust it's to be found.
Rocket-fuel in space - the ice can of course be electrolyzed into hydrogen and oxygen ready for compressing into the fuel tanks of exploratory craft, colonizers - even the asteroid itself could be nudged into a different orbit if thought desirable. Indefinite-stay on a space-laboratory would then become trivial. The moon could be more-easily mined for minerals with having easy access to the essentials, water, oxygen - leading to access to fabricated parts in space; parts for further craft and infrastructure to be built. Lunar tourism might begin.  Long-term exploration of the outer solar system might start again.

Feasibility of Asteroid Mining and Evolution of Mining Economy
TL;DR: It will probably not happen sooner, and also unlikely later on. The first thing will be exploiting moon's resources if needed and then mars' and so on.
There are quite some factors to consider here:
Return on Investment: If there is a regulatory institution that prevents amassing for example gold, silver, etc. to not crash the market, that aspect of "economy" is ruled out to change. The ROI has still to be high to even consider asteroid mining. This leads to the two major questions outlined further down: What do we need and what can we expect?
Mining Technology: Our asteroid missions are very frail. We can barely manage to land on an asteroid (instead of bouncing off) and just made the first baby steps on returning samples to earth (Osiris-Rex mission). Those samples are taken from near the surface. Far away from detecting, purposefully drilling, collecting and return almost pure "ore" instead of "lots of dirt and just a tiny bit of the good stuff" (bycatch has to be minimized somehow). The only way of detecting material composition we are capable of is crashing something into the asteroid/comet and analyse the particles coming off with mass spectography. Every mission also has to be meticulously planned in tiny-tiny steps, probe commands uploaded and then waited for the results to arrive earth. This is tedious, cost intensive and occupies man-power of a larger team to accomplish.
In other words: There have to be major scale improvements taking place to solve the technical side already. Let alone logistics (fuel, containers, rockets, factories, ...) or politics or financial stuff.
Signal Travel: "Safely beyond the moon orbit" is somewhat vague. But consider that signals sent to the moon take about 3 seconds to arrive earth again. However, Mars' orbit distance can vary between 3 and 22 light_minutes_ already (and this has to be doubled for a round-trip signal).
Human Remote Operators: Improving the effectiveness of the mining process, involving less planning and more "direct action-reaction behaviour" you can resort either to automation, that is A.I. has to do most of the work, or to semi-manual-remote mode: Humans sitting somewhere in a kind of simulator cockpit on earth and in fact playing a "space asteroid mining game" to get to the good stuff.
But as outlined with the signal travelling, the human option is only feasible within a certain distance. With 3 seconds of signal delay to the moon ("lag") this is actually too far away already to operate a drone precisely.
First major question: What do we want to mine after all? If precious metals are regulated they can only be useful in larger quantity for micro-electronics. Same goes for Rare-Earth-Minerals. Depending on the state of earth, hydrogen or water might be a resource needed in abundance to maintain survivability. Helium-3 has promising applications maybe.
Second major question: What can we expect to find on asteroids/comets actually?

Comets are primarily made of frozen gases. This can come down to frozen water ice when hydrogen is mixed with oxygen, but could also be frozen carbon-di-oxide (CO2, "dry ice") or just hydrogen or helium, maybe nitrogen. Some very low quantities are of solid substance and we call those "dirt", having low value for us (therefore dubbed "dirty snowballs").

Asteroids are considered to be of rocky density, implying heavier elements. However, In our current understanding heavier elements are "bred" by supernova explosions and neutron star mergers. According to this star nucleosynthesis, some elements can be considered being really rare, but also maybe of limited use nowadays; I refer to Beryllium and Bor here, created by cosmic ray fission. This means not every asteroid is guaranteed to be of "pure metals" or precious metals even. It is more likely there are traces of everything or something inside it, but also likely not localized on one spot but distributed across the whole asteroid. Making mining those traces cost-efficiently nigh to impossible.


Containers: Consider a probe at an remote asteroid having collected the wanted substances and now has to store it in some container to send them back to earth. Collecting dense, solid elements would have the best mass:volume-ratio (like gold etc.). While gases need a larger volume and have a lower mass yield even if frozen. In general you will want to minimize the needed containers per mining run of a probe with a maximized "filling quota" of wanted-to-unwanted materials.
Cargo Container Collection: Sending full containers back is only one part of the process and could be done with almost no need for active flight control at the cost of longer travel times maybe ("if full, controllably fire thrusters to get on trajectory back home", the rest will be done by gravity).
But you also need fresh empty ones at hand to not stall the mining probe from doing its work. This means there has to be some larger type of cargo vessel in the vicinity which enables a kind of turn-around-process on a short, managable distance. There are three types of "cargo collector stations" possible:

Earth: By far the approach with the highest costs. Because of atmospheric re-entry a container has limited reusability cycles. Also, to bring up fresh ones, a large rocket (or some carrier as mentioned) has to be run between earth's surface and the mining site in space constantly.
Fresh containers might be "thrown" from Low-Earth-Orbit to the mining site and "caught" there (needs a special vessel).
Or containers need thrusters to control the approach. But this also makes fuel, computer logic etc. necessary on the containers. Meaning: refurbishing costs are increased (drastically) and the results in the highest costs because of the need to escape earth's gravity each time.

Moon: A better approach might be to have na intermediate base/station on the moon where the containers are dropped off, emptied into something bigger and then quickly returned to the mining site again.
This enhances reusability cycles of the containers. Still, at some point there has to be a cargo haul from the moon to earth, unless there are factories or whatever that are the primary consumers of the stuff mined in space and a return to earth is not necessary.

Cargo Ship: This would be a versatile option because it can change location and be deployed to other mining sites later. Also allows "docking bays" for the mining probes enabling repairs and other maintenance (like refueling for example, also a major logistics challenge).


Intermediate Base: Considering the previous aspect there is another benefit on the horizon: If the remote human operators can be sustained in space on the moon or on a cargo vessel, this will shorten signal travel times drastically. This approach would allow for more deep space mining operations in the long run (if feasible; there are a bunch of whole other questions tied to this, like biological/psychological stability of humans living in deep space for elongated time periods etc.)
Concerning the moon as an intermediate base, this rises the question: Does it make sense to try to mine from an asteroid (further away) rather than from the moon itself, which also provides certain materials already and has lots of other benefits?
Conclusion:
The primary question is probably not "how" the economics of space mining would evolve but rather "if/when and why" it will evolve in the first place.
There have to be really major problems persisting on earth (and still high levels of technical capabilities) that space-mining could even possibly be considered the most viable option to go for.
Before we exploit the first asteroids on industrial scales, we surely will exploit the moon to an high extent first. Just because it is less costly to begin with. And afterwards we continue with mars, not asteroids, would be plausible.
If the first if's question of "why" can be answered, then there are the possibilities open to examine as sketched out in this answer.

FRAME CHALLENGE:
If you can grab even one decently-sized asteroid, and somehow tow it from post lunar orbit, to low Earth Orbit, economics no longer matter, because you now hold a tremendous weapon of mass destruction over the entire planet.
The rock that killed the dinosaurs was barely 10 km long, that's a pebble by asteroid standards. The Asteroid belt has beauties in the 200-900 km size range, and uncountable number of asteroids in the dozen-kilometer range. Park any of these baddies on a convenient orbit so that the Earthers can see it on the sky, and you can negotiate any economic treaty you want.
Any kind of "mine the asteroids" scenario where the mining is worth it, becomes "do as we say or the rock drops" scenario pretty easily. In fact, large part of the cost and technological effort would need to be put into not doing it by accident. Sending down 1000 tons of palladium ore down the gravity well would net you nice profit, but not so when the hill-sized palladium chunk hits Baltimore at 20 kilometers per second. That might make people upset with you (albeit briefly).

Isn't that effectively the same as MAD with nuclear weapons. yeah you could but your gonna die as well.

No, because there is no M in MAD here. The first team/corp/gov that parks an asteroid around Earth wins totally. There is no real option to knock them off the sky, either with nukes or another asteroid, that would not endanger Earth, or fail hilariously. Space if VERY big, and shooting down an object in the orbit without them noticing the attempt and dodging effortlessly is borderline impossible. Earth vs Asteroid Terrorists is the perfect asymmetric warfare scenario for the latter, because Earth can't dodge the asteroid, nor shoot it down, even if it was just flying randomly, and not towed.

I mean yeah they won't immediately die but they're gonna starve to death when they've destroyed earth and there's no one left to keep shipping up food, medicine, etc.

@OT-64SKOT they do not need to absolutely destroy the Earth. Just say, glass Denver, Shenzou and St.Petersburg by dropping some rocks, and then their demands would be taken much more seriously. Or maybe even not hurt anyone, just drop a hill-sized rock in the middle of Sahara, to show what they are capable of.

At that point you've effectively just done the same thing you would as if you'd nuked those cities and whoever did it is probably going to either going to have all their supply launches cut off or receive nuclear retaliation.

If there are possibilities to tow an asteroid into a stable orbit around earth, this does not guarantee that the ones who brought it are also the ones keeping it under control. If there are possible ways of letting the asteroid or parts of it fall to earth in a controlled/targeted fashion, then there are probably more nations than just one to pull that off. This makes it unlikely to have a "blackmailing" scenario. More like another level of "stalemate".

The dirt-cheap parts are the most valuable ones
So you have a giant chunk of iron and nickel in space.
And you want to build big structures (solar sattelites) in high orbit.
I say, forget about rare earth elements, your market is right there, if you manage to refine iron to manufacture structural parts in space and ship it to orbit.
Sell a megaton of steel beams directly in geosynchronous orbit rather than a few grams of platinum on earth.
The delta-v required to bring the stuff there should be tiny compared to getting it up there from earth, or getting it from the asteroid belt - which  energetically would still be better, but a logistical nightmare to send humans there, or to make it 100% automated from the very start.
A moon distance away however, there it is feasible to send a human crew for initial setup of and later for maintenance.
This could then kickstart an orbital industry that strifes to manufacture more and more complicated parts in orbit to become even less dependent on launching heavy and bulky stuff from earth.

16 Psyche weighs in at 2 x 10^16 tonnes so is not going to be moved by any human intervention any time soon and perhaps ever. So the only option would be set up a facility on or near the surface for mining what is required.
So first gamble how much do you want to invest in new space refining technology? Is it better to simply drill into the asteroid and bring the spoil home to refine on Earth? Or is it better spend even more money to concentrate specific elements from the asteroid?
Second gamble how much will it cost to send ships to the asteroid (including refilling in orbit), set up the mining operation in micro gravity (robotically?) and send the materials back to Earth (and maintain the mining facility)?
Third gamble how profitable would it actually be and how well would it stand up to the vagaries of the markets especially to the sentiments of the gold market (are you feeling lucky?).
Fourth if it is profitable, what's to stop other nations cashing in and ultimately crashing the markets (regardless of what Congress direct).
I doubt that any such operation would be viable currently. The amount of initial investment that would needed and the level of risks involved would be too great. May be come back in 50-100 years and we can review it then.

Absolutely, but not for terrestrial industry, more for having at hand resources to build space infrastructure. There would probably be a race to claim it for one nation or group of nations.
It would be a massive savings if we don't have to launch everything up out of our gravity well if the resources are right there already. (still would need to launch material to build the infrastructure for the initial refining and manufacturing)
